# How can I "Print Preview" of document created by QTextDocument in PyQt5?

Tags: python, printing, pyqt5, print-preview, qtextdocument

**Hello Experts!!** I hope you are having great day. I am new in GUI programming specially PyQt5. I am practicing on simple GUI invoice application. In this application, I successfully generated the Invoice By QTextDocument. Now i want to add print dialogue and print preview option. I am having trouble in the code. This is saying

> AttributeError: 'InvoiceForm' object has no attribute
> 'printpreviewDialog

As i am new, i am little bit confused in there. Could you please fix the code? That will help me a lot to study. Many Many Thanks.
The code has given below:-

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize, QSizeF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPlainTextEdit, QSpinBox, QDateEdit, QTableWidget, \
    QHeaderView, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow

font= QFont('Arial',16)

class InvoiceForm(QWidget):
    submitted = pyqtSignal(dict)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setLayout(QFormLayout())
        self.inputs = dict()
        self.inputs['Customer Name'] = QLineEdit()
        self.inputs['Customer Address'] = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.inputs['Invoice Date'] = QDateEdit(date=QDate.currentDate(), calendarPopup=True)
        self.inputs['Days until Due'] = QSpinBox()
        for label, widget in self.inputs.items():
            self.layout().addRow(label, widget)

        self.line_items = QTableWidget(rowCount=10, columnCount=3)
        self.line_items.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Job', 'Rate', 'Hours'])
        self.line_items.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.layout().addRow(self.line_items)
        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.line_items.columnCount()):
                if col > 0:
                    w = QSpinBox()
                    self.line_items.setCellWidget(row, col, w)

        submit = QPushButton('Create Invoice', clicked=self.on_submit)
        print = QPushButton('Print Invoice', clicked=self.printpreviewDialog)
        self.layout().addRow(submit,print)

    def on_submit(self):
        data = {'c_name': self.inputs['Customer Name'].text(),
                'c_addr': self.inputs['Customer Address'].toPlainText(),
                'i_date': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().toString(),
                'i_due': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().addDays(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()).toString(),
                'i_terms': '{} days'.format(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()),
                'line_items': list()}

        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            if not self.line_items.item(row, 0):
                continue
            job = self.line_items.item(row, 0).text()
            rate = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 1).value()
            hours = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 2).value()
            total = rate * hours
            row_data = [job, rate, hours, total]
            if any(row_data):
                data['line_items'].append(row_data)

        data['total_due'] = sum(x[3] for x in data['line_items'])
        self.submitted.emit(data)
        # remove everything else in this function below this point

class InvoiceView(QTextEdit):
    dpi = 72
    doc_width = 8.5 * dpi
    doc_height = 6 * dpi

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(readOnly=True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))

    def build_invoice(self, data):
        document = QTextDocument()
        self.setDocument(document)
        document.setPageSize(QSizeF(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))
        document.setDefaultFont(font)
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertText(f"Customer Name: {data['c_name']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Customer Address: {data['c_addr']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Date: {data['i_date']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Total Due: {data['total_due']}\n")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central)

        self.invoiceForm = InvoiceForm()
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceForm)

        self.invoiceView = InvoiceView()
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceView)
        # hide the widget right now...
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(False)

        self.invoiceForm.submitted.connect(self.showPreview)

    def showPreview(self, data):
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(True)
        self.invoiceView.build_invoice(data)

    def printpreviewDialog(self):
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, self)
        previewDialog.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview)
        previewDialog.exec_()

    def printPreview(self, printer):
        self.invoiceView.build_invoice.print_(printer)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: While we appreciate your courtesy, please avoid greetings at the beginning of your questions, they take a considerable amount of space that should show the actual contents of the question instead, mostly because they appear in the summary of search results; remember that questions and answers are useful to everybody, at any time, and people looking for a problem similar to yours prefers to scroll through dozens of question summaries, and is hardly interested in reading how kind you are :-)

Comment: @musicamante As i remember, i have added the greetings. But somehow, it did not publish. Although i was in hurry, so i had no time to read the question. Thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: No. Please carefully read what I wrote, because that's exactly the opposite of what I told you. Do **NOT** add greetings at the beginning of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `self.printpreviewDialog` is a member of `MainWindow`, not of `InvoiceForm`, so you should connect the `clicked` signal from the main window instead.

Also note that you tried to use `self.invoiceView.build_invoice.print_()`, but this wouldn't work as you are not *calling* `build_invoice`, and even if you did, that function doesn't return anything.

You should use the `self.invoiceView.document()` instead, but you must ensure that the data has been built before.

```
class InvoiceForm(QWidget):
    submitted = pyqtSignal(dict)
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        submit = QPushButton('Create Invoice', clicked=self.on_submit)
        # make the button a member of the instance instead of a local variable, 
        # so that we can connect from the main window instance
        self.printButton = QPushButton('Print Invoice')
        self.layout().addRow(submit, self.printButton)

# ...

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.invoiceForm.printButton.clicked.connect(self.printpreviewDialog)
    # ...

    def printPreview(self, printer):
        self.invoiceView.document().print_(printer)
```

Note: never, **never** use built-in functions and statements for variable names, like `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QSize, QSizeF, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QFormLayout, QLineEdit, QPlainTextEdit, 
    QSpinBox, QDateEdit, QTableWidget, QHeaderView, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, 
    QTextEdit, QApplication, QMainWindow)


font = QFont('Arial',16)


class InvoiceForm(QWidget):
    submitted = pyqtSignal(dict)
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                        # + parent=None
        super().__init__(parent)                                            # + parent
        self.setLayout(QFormLayout())
        self.inputs = dict()
        self.inputs['Customer Name'] = QLineEdit()
        self.inputs['Customer Address'] = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.inputs['Invoice Date'] = QDateEdit(date=QDate.currentDate(), calendarPopup=True)
        self.inputs['Days until Due'] = QSpinBox()
        for label, widget in self.inputs.items():
            self.layout().addRow(label, widget)

        self.line_items = QTableWidget(rowCount=10, columnCount=3)
        self.line_items.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Job', 'Rate', 'Hours'])
        self.line_items.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.layout().addRow(self.line_items)
        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.line_items.columnCount()):
                if col > 0:
                    w = QSpinBox()
                    self.line_items.setCellWidget(row, col, w)

        submit = QPushButton('Create Invoice', clicked=self.on_submit)
        
# +     vvvvvv                                        vvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        _print = QPushButton('Print Invoice', clicked=self.window().printpreviewDialog)  # + _print, + self.window()
        self.layout().addRow(submit, _print)                                             # + _print

    def on_submit(self):
        data = {'c_name': self.inputs['Customer Name'].text(),
                'c_addr': self.inputs['Customer Address'].toPlainText(),
                'i_date': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().toString(),
                'i_due': self.inputs['Invoice Date'].date().addDays(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()).toString(),
                'i_terms': '{} days'.format(self.inputs['Days until Due'].value()),
                'line_items': list()}

        for row in range(self.line_items.rowCount()):
            if not self.line_items.item(row, 0):
                continue
            job = self.line_items.item(row, 0).text()
            rate = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 1).value()
            hours = self.line_items.cellWidget(row, 2).value()
            total = rate * hours
            row_data = [job, rate, hours, total]
            if any(row_data):
                data['line_items'].append(row_data)

        data['total_due'] = sum(x[3] for x in data['line_items'])
        self.submitted.emit(data)
        # remove everything else in this function below this point
# +
        return data                                                            # +++
        

class InvoiceView(QTextEdit):
    dpi = 72
    doc_width = 8.5 * dpi
    doc_height = 6 * dpi

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(readOnly=True)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))

    def build_invoice(self, data):
        document = QTextDocument()
        self.setDocument(document)
        document.setPageSize(QSizeF(self.doc_width, self.doc_height))
        document.setDefaultFont(font)
        cursor = QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertText(f"Customer Name: {data['c_name']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Customer Address: {data['c_addr']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Date: {data['i_date']}\n")
        cursor.insertText(f"Total Due: {data['total_due']}\n")
# +        
        return document                                                         # +++
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(central)
# +                                    vvvv
        self.invoiceForm = InvoiceForm(self)                                    # + self
        
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceForm)
        self.invoiceView = InvoiceView()
        layout.addWidget(self.invoiceView)
        # hide the widget right now...
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(False)
        self.invoiceForm.submitted.connect(self.showPreview)

    def showPreview(self, data):
        self.invoiceView.setVisible(True)
        self.invoiceView.build_invoice(data)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def printpreviewDialog(self):
        previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
        previewDialog.paintRequested.connect(self.printPreview)  
        previewDialog.exec_()

    def printPreview(self, printer):
#        self.invoiceView.build_invoice.print_(printer)        
        data = self.invoiceForm.on_submit()
        document = self.invoiceView.build_invoice(data)
        document.print_(printer)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]